# Flutter Dynamically insert and remove `TextFormField` from UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to insert `TextFormField` on a click to take the name of the student. This thing is working fine. But the problem is when I integrate remove functionality than it's not working as expected.
I did take `List<Student>` to insert and remove items and converted this `List` into `Map` to plot items to UI and update user input name value to a specific indexed `Student` object value.

If we try adding items and removing them serially than it'll work fine but the only issue is when I remove a single item from in-between it will only update my `List` and `Map` but UI will not get updated. This is my code

```
import 'package:dynamic_input_add_flutter/student.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SingleListUse extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String tag = 'single-list-use';
  @override
  _SingleListUseState createState() => _SingleListUseState();
}

class Student1 {
  String _name;
  int _sessionId;

  Student1(this._name, this._sessionId);

  String get name => _name;

  set name(String value) {
    _name = value;
  }

  int get sessionId => _sessionId;

  set sessionId(int value) {
    _sessionId = value;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Student $_name from session $_sessionId';
  }
}

class _SingleListUseState extends State<SingleListUse> {
  List<Student1> _studentList = [];
  Map<int, Student1> _studentMap = {};

  void _addNewStudent() {
    setState(() {
      _studentList.add(Student1('', 1));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.done,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (_studentList.length != 0) {
            _studentList.forEach((student) => print(student.toString()));
          } else {
            print('map list empty');
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Single Map Use'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _addNewStudent();
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            print("List : ${_studentList.toString()}");
            _studentMap = _studentList.asMap();
            print("MAP : ${_studentMap.toString()}");
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _studentMap.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                print('Item Position $position');
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _studentMap[position].name.length != 0
                              ? _studentMap[position].name
                              : '',
                          onFieldSubmitted: (name) {
                            setState(() {
                              _studentList[position].name = name;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'enter student name',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.black26,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.black12,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(15.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.delete,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _studentList.removeAt(position);
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

The first image is when we add a Student name in plus icon click.(every item in `List` is a `TextFormField`. When I remove the second item from UI it will remove 3rd one while technically from data structure that I've used (`List` & `Map`) it's removing 2nd (and that's ok). I have an issue of displayed UI after we perform any delete from between.

Comment: Please tell us what is the issue. You have only said what you are doing and that you have an issue when you remove an item.

Comment: @JoãoSoares please check I've added issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is state-full widget make a variable `bool showTextFormField = false` in state class

now in widget use `if(showTextFormField) <Widget>`

now on button click

```
setState(){
  showTextFormField = true;
}
```

Comment: I think you might have took it different way. I want to manage it like a `List` of `Student Objects` each by having a `TexyFormField` to input Student name.

Comment: for that you can bool[] showTextFormField with all elements false initially for the length of students and set and  show as per showTextFormField [i]